# COUNT number distinct when they a row hasn't existed before the time period

Tags: mysql, sql

I have kind of an interesting situation that I will try my best to explain.

I have a table called `appointments` in that table holds many appointments that a sales person can have with a potential customer. The relationship between appointments to salespeople is many to one and it is the same for potential customers.

I need to count how many appointments a salesperson has set with a lead *when that salesperson has never set an appointment with that lead before.*

Here is how far I have gotten in the code (I'm trying to see how many appointments a salesperson set yesterday, hence the date scrub):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT lead) 
FROM appointments 
WHERE status = 3 
  and DATE(appointment_created_at) = CURDATE() - interval 1 day 
  AND creator = 'xxx';
```

(the column `creator` represents the individual sales person and the column `lead` represents the individual potential customer)

The problem with this SQL query is that if a salesperson is *resetting* an appointment with a lead they have already set an appointment with, it still counts it as a "set appointment".

**How can I count the number of rows in my appointments table without counting leads who have already been set before?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize `NOT EXISTS()` to check if an appointment already exists earlier or not.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a1.lead) 
FROM appointments a1
WHERE a1.status = 3 
  and a1.appointment_created_at >= CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
  AND a1.appointment_created_at < CURRENT_DATE()
  AND a1.creator = 'xxx' 
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM appointments a2 
                  WHERE a2.creator = 'xxx' 
                        AND a2.lead = a1.lead 
                        AND a2.appointment_created_at < a1.appointment_created_at)
```

For good performance, for the Correlated subquery in the `NOT EXISTS()` portion, you can use the following composite index: `(creator, lead, appointment_created_at)`

And, for the main select query, you can add the following the composite index: `(creator, status, appointment_created_at)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the number of "first-time" appointments, you can use `row_number()` or a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM appointments a
WHERE a.status = 3 AND
      a.appointment_created_at >= CURDATE() - interval 1 day AND
      a.appointment_created_at < CURDATE()  AND
      a.creator = 'xxx' AND
      a.appointment_created_at = (SELECT MIN(a2.appointment_created_at)
                                  FROM appointments a2
                                  WHERE a2.creator = a.creator AND
                                        a2.lead = a.lead
                                 );
```

Notice that I changed the date comparisons so an index can be used for the `WHERE` clause.  If you care about performance, you want indexes on:

- `appointments(creator, status, appointment_created_at, lead)`
- `appointments(creator, lead, appointment_created_at)`.

Answer (score 0):

If the sales people can reschedule appointments then you are going to need an additional field to store original appointment date, at least.  There are other more complex solutions, but this is probably the easiest approach.